# Returning -1 to a user defined function is resulting to termination of program with exit code 0

Tags: c, return, factorial

In this factorial program when entered any non numeric or negative number then the program should ask to renter the value but in the output the program is getting terminated.

Is it because I am returning `-1` in `display()` function? If so then is it compulsory to return a variable (or other function) value to a function if the function is meant to return a value?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int display();
void fact_fun(int num_fact);

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    char next;

    next = display();

    if (next == -1) { //WHEN ANY CHARACTER OR NEGATIVE NUMBER IS ENTERED IT WILL ASK TO RENTER
        printf("\nOnly positive number is allowed");
        display();
    }

    while (next >= 0) { //WHEN NEGATIVE NUMBER IS ENTERED IT WILL END THE LOOP
        num = next;
        fact_fun(num);
        next = display();
    }
    return 0;
}

int display() {
    char inp[10] = { 0 };
    int input;
    int index = 0;
    printf("\nEnter number to find factorial or press ENTER KEY to exit: ");

    while (((input = getchar()) != EOF) & (index < 10)) {
        if ((input >= '0') && (input <= '9')) {
            inp[index++] = input;
        } else
        if (input == '\n')
            break;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    input = atoi(inp);

    return input;
}

void fact_fun(int num_fact) {
    int fact = 1;
    if (num_fact == 0) {
        printf("\nFactorial of %d is 1", num_fact);
        return;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num_fact; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        printf("\nFactorial of %d is %d", num_fact, fact);
    }
}
```

Also when I press ENTER KEY I am getting output as below:

```
Factorial of %d is 1
Enter number to find factorial or press ENTER KEY to exit:
```

And when enter `\n` the program gets terminate. As per my understanding it should treat the Enter key and `\n` same. If not then what is the difference and how should I check for ENTER KEY value?

Comment: "...is it compulsory to return a variable(or other function) value to a function if the function is meant to return a value?" - you answered your question yourself: if a function is meant to return something of a non-void type, then you _must_ return something inside this function.

Comment: Rather than make a guess a what could be wrong, and ask whether your guess is right, it would be better to simply ask what is wrong with the code.  The answer to your question is simply "_yes, you can_" so now how much further forward are you!?  Functions are just functions there is no difference, between those you write or library functions.  With respect to returning a value from a function defined as returning a value yes it is required - but the compiler will tell you if you did not do so.

Comment: "terminated"?  With an error message, or just ended with unexpected (or no) result?

Comment: Take a look at `while(((input=getchar())!=EOF)&(index<10))` - you almost certainly did not intend to use bitwise `&` there - more likely `&&`.  Debugging by SO will not be very productive; learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Clifford ended with `The program has exited with code 0 (0x0)`

Comment: @ForceBru It means return statement cannot be used to return any value to user defined function

Comment: @VasudhaDixit, why, you can return whatever you want. You can even change the return type in the function's signature, and it'll still "work" (that is, the code will compile with warnings).

Comment: @ForceBru I am returning -1 due to which program is getting finished with exit code 0

Comment: Update your question to address the comments.  Critically you need ot explain what input you gave and what output resulted and what output you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User input is line buffered by default. It is much simpler for your purpose to read input one line at a time from the user, parse it to assert input validity and compute the factorial only for valid input.

Note also that you can simplify the computation as the special case for `0` is redundant with the code for the general case. You should also check for potential arithmetic overflow as the computation may easily exceed the range of type `int` and produce undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int display();
void fact_fun(int num_fact);

int main() {
    int num;
    while ((num = display()) >= 0) {
        fact_fun(num);
    }
    return 0;
}

int display() {
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    long value;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter number to find factorial or press ENTER KEY to exit: ");
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL || *buf == '\n')
            return -1;
        errno = 0;
        value = strtol(buf, &p, 0);
        if (p == buf) {
            printf("Invalid input: not a number\n");
        } else {
        if (value < 0) {
            printf("Invalid input: negative values not allowed\n");
        } else
        if (errno != 0 || value > INT_MAX) {
            printf("Invalid input: value too large for type int\n");
        } else {
            return (int)value;
        }
    }
}

void fact_fun(int num_fact) {
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_fact; i++) {
        if (fact > INT_MAX / i) {
            printf("Invalid input: arithmetic overflow\n");
            return;
        }
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d\n", num_fact, fact);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: The program is not working for input `5r` i.e in input when first character has number and remaining next character has any alphabet or negative number. So I tried putting check for strtol unsuccessful conversion :- `if (p == buf || *p != '\0'){
            printf("\nInvalid input: not a number\n");}` but I am getting output as `Invalid input: not a number` for all the input. I am not understanding what is wrong with this simple check? How can I successfully detect errors from strtol?

Comment: @VasudhaDixit: there is a trailing newline in the buffer, test for `*p == '\n'` too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with some corrections. There were two problems.

The first is that you have to finish reading the input until you reach an end of the line or EOF.

The second is that you need two error codes, one for invalid input, and a second for no-input.  (Your comment in the code indicates that you want to exit on no-input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int display();
void fact_fun(int num_fact);

int main() {
  //int num = 0;
    char next;

    while( 1 ) {

      next = display();
      if (next == -2) {
    break;
      }

      if (next == -1) {
    //WHEN ANY CHARACTER OR NEGATIVE NUMBER IS ENTERED IT WILL ASK TO RENTER
        printf("\nOnly positive number is allowed");
      }

      else {

        fact_fun(next);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}

int display() {
    char inp[10] = { 0 };
    char c;
    int input = 0;
    int index = 0;
    printf("\nEnter number to find factorial or press ENTER KEY to exit: ");

    while ( ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n') && (index < 10)) {
      if ( (c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ) {
    inp[index++] = c;
      } else {
    input = -1;
    break;
      }
    }

    // Finish inputting the line
    while ( (c != EOF) && (c != '\n') ) {
      c = getchar();
    }

    if ( !input ) {
      if ( index )
    input = atoi(inp);
      else
    input = -2;
    }

    return input;
}

void fact_fun(int num_fact) {
    int fact = 1;
    if (num_fact == 0) {
        printf("\nFactorial of %d is 1", num_fact);
        return;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num_fact; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        printf("\nFactorial of %d is %d", num_fact, fact);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this factorial program when entered any non numeric or negative number then the program should ask to renter the value

The `while` loop in your `main()` function only loops to ask for new numbers until `input()` returns a negative number. You have even documented it:

```
while(next>=0) //WHEN NEGATIVE NUMBER IS ENTERED IT WILL END THE LOOP
...
```

When you do `return -1` in `input()`, the function returns -1, which will set `next` to -1 and end the loop. The program then exists shortly after that.

There is nothing inherently wrong with using a `return` statement to return `-1` from a user defined function. It's quite normal and common to do things like that.